# opencv cmake files, how to use them in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, cmake

These stuff stuck me another 3 days to figure out.

I'm implementing opencv and I need to use **xfeatures2d** module in **objc** **xcode**.  I previously downloaded the **opencv.framework** and successfully imported it in my iOS project and it works.  But there is no xfeatures2d in it.  So then I finally figured out that it is an **extra module** and it is in a package call **opencv_contrib**.

To make use of it, it seems like people recommend to use [cmake](https://cmake.org/install/) to build the source code of [opencv-master](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) with [opencv-contrib-master](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib)

I did it, and it looks build correctly.  And I got lots of funky things in my folder.  However, it seems like nothing I can use to #import to my .xcodeproj project.  (Sorry I can't embed my screenshot yet.)

So did I do something wrong? Or,is it the correct way to build the file I need??

Please help, Thanks!

Comment: This may sound dumb, but how does one import the modules (i.e. SIFT)? I tried a combination including `<opencv2/xfeatures2d/xfeatures2d.hpp>`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found a solution.  @thachnb 's solution is referred from [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html#ios-installation).  This instruction guide you to generate an opencv2.framework in use of your iOS project from the **opencv-master** package.  If you want to use the modules in opencv_contrib, you need to physically copy the module from **opencv_contrib**(in my case is xfeatures2d, or you can just copy everything over), to **opencv-master/module**, and then use

> python opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py ios

command to compile it.  After this compilation, you will have a opencv2.framework containing everything you need.  [This](http://answers.opencv.org/question/40392/how-to-build-opencv_contrib-module-for-ios/) also helps.

Thanks @thachnb !

Answer (score 1):

Q1. Did you run below command?

```
python opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py ios
```

if yes, move to question 2

Q2. Did you see opencv.framework in ios subfolder?

if yes, move to question 3

Q3. Did you add that opencv.framework folder to your xcode project? or drag and drop it to Framework folder of your xcode project?

Comment: Hi, I've tried the python command just a moment ago.  It works and I found the opencv2.framework(it's 2GB large..) and successfully import it.  However, I found there is no **xfeatures2d** module in it.. It is likely the opencv2.framework that I downloaded on line.  Does the python command suppose to embed the opencv_contrib module into the opencv2.framework?